# Add column to a report via API

Tags: api, reporting, metadata-api, reports-api, analytics-api

Is it possible to add a column to a report via API call? 
I have a folder with 50 reports that I need to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add columns to report. As per documentaion : -

> Use the report object to get report metadata. Query, search, or
>   retrieve specific metadata on reports. **Report object fields are
>   read-only.**

Comment: Hmm having another look. There is a patch request available in REST API one could in theory use detail column property to do update. I haven't test it. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_list_resource.htm#analytics_api_report_list_resource